# how to buy eth to my metamask 's wallet in private network?

Tags: metamask

in the metamask i am using the private network - Localhost 8545 for the development, however in the private network, my wallet is empty eth, how would i buy some fake eth for the testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [`testrpc`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) then you can have accounts initialized with some eth when you start testrpc.

```
$ testrpc --account="0x7231a774a538fce22a329729b03087de4cb4a1119494db1c10eae3bb491823e7, 10000000000000000000"
```

The `--account` option takes a private key, and the eth amount in wei.

`1` eth is `1000000000000000000` wei. Here's a [converter](https://etherconverter.online/).

Note: exporting the private key from MetaMask doesn't prefix it with `0x` so make sure to add it when passing it to the testrpc command.

By default, testrpc generates 10 random accounts with 100 eth each. You can pass a mnemonic to testrpc so that it always generate the same account addresses for your testing in MetaMask.

```
$ testrpc -m "tower wish sleep air brave candy shop employ quarter sell country exotic"
```

Comment: I tried ‘testrpc --debug --account="0x2AD5D29E7d38D0D46FC4118E6EbDa85CC1400F81,100000000000000000"
’, but got a error  'RangeError: private key length is invalid'.

Comment: @user824624 that looks like the public key. Exporting private key in MetaMask https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZ6o6P6QRfrs2f1PQSJCft6YeoVVEE6Gc55yd5bePpS7v

Comment: @user824624 exporting the private key from MetaMask doesn't remove the account so the account should still be there and you can export the private key as many times as you want

Comment: @user824624 exporting the private key from MetaMask doesn't prefix the key with `0x` so you have to it when passing it to the testrpc command

Comment: i found the private key, and I tried again 'testrpc --account="a1b0fed9b2396058c4b7aecec1d00a2bae7532632ba44231aa5a60c2070c8076,100000000000000000"
' , but still with private key length is invalid

Comment: Add `0x` to the beginning of the key